# WP: Blank date/time from php time()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Here is some curious behaviour. In a WP site, there is this bit of code to update a table with a date string.

The curious thing is that some times the string ($today) gets added to the db whilst some other times it doesn't (NULL value).

DB is MySQL.

The other field (`active`) get updated correctly every time.

```
        $today = date('Y-m-d',time());

        $upd=$my_db->prepare("UPDATE my_table SET active=1, my_date='".$today."' WHERE field_number=?");
        $upd->bindParam(1, $field_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $upd->execute();
```

Has anyone seen this? I'm pulling off my hair on this... I've added a small amateur workaround, which I don't know if it will work:

Replacing `date('Y-m-d',time());` with `date('Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' ));`, ie using WP's timestamp function... That should not be necessary, though...

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but you don't have to pass time() into date, if the second parameter is blank then it automatically gets the current time. What's the data type of the column in mysql?

Comment: Do you really have to calculate datetime on the server side, and not on the database layer? I mean, what's wrong with simple... `UPDATE my_table SET active=1, my_date=CURDATE() WHERE field_number=?`?

Comment: @raina77ow that is indeed an excellent suggestion. Thanks. I'll check it out. In the meantime, you could make that an answer and I'll come back to choose if everything is fine in a couple of days.

Comment: Can you get an example of the data for the a time when it works, and the times when it doesn't? (Don't forget to include the value of `$field_number` of course. I can't see how the date stuff wouldn't be working, given what you've described, so we probably need more detail to work out what's going on...)

Comment: There's no specific motive, either the date gets recorded or it's null. The query executes and the active flag gets set, but no date. There's no other way to set the active flag than this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to involve PHP code in simple datetime calculations; database can manage it easily with its own [stack of related functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Just rewrite your query into something like...

```
UPDATE my_table SET active=1, my_date=CURDATE() WHERE field_number=?
```